# Как работать с inlinekeyboard в pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, но почему я не могу добавить инлайн клавиатуру к сообщению.
Возможно я где-то прошляпил строку, где пишут, что юзер боты не могут добавлять клавиатуру, поэтому надеюсь, что вы подскажите, в чем проблема.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
app = Client(name='user_bot', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 1", callback_data="button1")],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 2", callback_data="button2")]
    ])
    message.reply_text("Ответ с клавиатурой", reply_markup=keyboard)

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления инлайн клавиатуры к сообщению в Pyrogram, нужно использовать классы `InlineKeyboardMarkup` и `InlineKeyboardButton` из модуля `pyrogram.types`.
В вашем коде вы уже используете эти классы, поэтому проблема, скорее всего, не в этом.
Возможно, вы забыли добавить обработчик для `callback_query` в вашем боте. Для того, чтобы обрабатывать нажатия на кнопки, необходимо добавить обработчик `callback_query` в ваш код.
Вот пример кода, который добавляет обработчик `callback_query` и позволяет обрабатывать нажатия на кнопки:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

app = Client(name='user_bot', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

# Обработчик команды /start
@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 1", callback_data="button1")],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 2", callback_data="button2")]
    ])
    message.reply_text("Ответ с клавиатурой", reply_markup=keyboard)

# Обработчик нажатий на кнопки
@app.on_callback_query()
def handle_callback_query(client, query):
    if query.data == "button1":
        # Действия при нажатии на кнопку 1
        pass
    elif query.data == "button2":
        # Действия при нажатии на кнопку 2
        pass

app.run()
```

Также, убедитесь, что вы используете правильный токен бота и правильно настроили его доступ к **API Telegram**.
Ниже приведены ссылки на документацию `Pyrogram` и `Stack Overflow`, которые могут помочь вам решить вашу проблему:

`**[InlineKeyboardButton — Pyrogram Documentation]**`
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/InlineKeyboardButton

`**[Как работать с inlinekeyboard в pyrogram - Stack Overflow на русском]**`
[Как работать с inlinekeyboard в pyrogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531005/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-inlinekeyboard-%D0%B2-pyrogram)

`**[Dont send message with inlinekeyboard pyrogram - Stack Overflow]**`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187717/dont-send-message-with-inlinekeyboard-pyrogram